# How to append a custom meta field as a shortcode argument value in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, shortcode

I have created a custom checkbox field `_is_group` and i would like to be able to use this in the `[products...]` shortcode.

The currently used workaround is that I create the query with `wc_get_products()` first and then pass the returned `IDs` to the standard shortcode, with `implode()` function:

```php
$group = wc_get_products([
    'post_type'     => 'product',
    'meta_key'      => '_is_group',
    'meta_value'    => 'yes',
    'meta_compare'  => 'IN',
    'return'        => 'ids'
]);

echo do_shortcode('[products ids="' . implode(',', $group) . '"]');
```

Sure it works, but it looks ugly, making unnecessarily two db queries instead of one. I think there is a better way to deal with it, something like that:

```
[products columns="3" is_group="yes"]
```

So I decided to ask how to append a custom meta field as a shortcode argument value in Woocommerce . Maybe the solution is to use `woocommerce_shortcode_products_query` or something else?

*Note: I've seen other similar questions and solutions like using custom shortcode inside another shortcode, but that doesn't solve the problem. I care about optimization*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two parts:

1. Support your own attribute for the `[products]` shortcode.

   - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/shortcode_atts_shortcode/

```php
// Add your own attribute
function filter_shortcode_atts_products( $out, $pairs, $atts, $shortcode ) {
    // Isset and equal to yes
    if ( isset ( $atts['is_group'] ) && $atts['is_group'] == 'yes' ) {
        $out['is_group'] = true;
    } else {
        $out['is_group'] = false;
    }
    
    return $out;
}
add_filter( 'shortcode_atts_products', 'filter_shortcode_atts_products', 10, 4 );
```

2. Modify the query to use your `$query_args`

```php
// Modify the query args 
function filter_woocommerce_shortcode_products_query( $query_args, $atts, $type ) {
    // Target
    if ( $type == 'products' && $atts['is_group'] ) {
        // Meta query       
        $query_args['meta_query'] = array(
            array(
                'key'     => '_is_group',
                'value'   => 'yes',
                'compare' => 'IN',
            )
        );
    }

    return $query_args;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', 'filter_woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', 10, 3 );
```

---

> **SHORTCODE USAGE**
>
> In an existing page:
>
> `[products columns="3" is_group="yes"]`
>
> Or in PHP:
>
> `echo do_shortcode('[products columns="3" is_group="yes"]');`